# How to use 0 as an identifier for a workspace in awesome wm?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, awesome-wm

Is it possible to use `0` as an identifier for a workspace in awesome wm? By default it only allows the numbers from 1 to 9. I would like to switch to the workspace just like any other (e.g. <kbd>mod</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>). 
Ideally it would be added after the 9th workspace and not appended to the front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are coming from the [default](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/sample%20files/rc.lua.html) `rc.lua` search for something like this in it and let the for loop run until 10 instead of 9.

```
-- Bind all key numbers to tags.
-- Be careful: we use keycodes to make it work on any keyboard layout.
-- This should map on the top row of your keyboard, usually 1 to 9.
for i = 1, 9 do
```

You have set up the key bindings, now create an additional tag. Somewhere you can find something like this. Add a "0" to the list.

```
awful.tag({ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}, s, awful.layout.layouts[1])
```